# count the characters entered into a textbox c#. winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Fairly simple problem here. I have and if/else statement that i need to run when the textbox length is 3 or 4, as in user enters 12, skips if/else, user types 123, runs if/else. This will all be run through the textbox_textchanged event.

```
if (fanRPM >= classRPM)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("hi");
                    }
                    else if (fanRPM < classRPM)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hide");
                    }
```

This is my if/else that needs to run.

Comment: What about `Textbox.Text.Length` to know the Length of your texts?

Comment: What are `fanRPM` and `classRPM` at all?

Comment: Your code can be simplified to `MessageBox.Show(fanRPM < classRPM ? "Hide" : "hi")`

Comment: fanrpm is what the user is entering, and classrpm is a value from a database its comparing it too . the "hi" and "hide" are just filler text atm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
if(txtBox.Text.Trim().Length == 3 || txtBox.Text.Trim().Length == 4 )
{
  if (fanRPM >= classRPM)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("hi");
  }
  else if (fanRPM < classRPM)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Hide");
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks, ran into another issue elsewhere, but oh well haha.

Answer (score 1):

Or like Sergey suggests:

```
if (txtBox.Text.Trim().Length == 3 || txtBox.Text.Trim().Length == 4 )
    MessageBox.Show(fanRPM < classRPM ? "Hide" : "hi");
```

Comment: thanks i have a few other areas this code will help reduce some lines, for this particular spot though ill be adding more lines so i just posted a basic outline.